# Express generator with Swig

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I'm trying to use Express generator to create the application skeleton, however it seems to work only with Jade and EJS.

I don't like the idea from Jade of not using tags, because the code becomes a complete mess. And I already started working with Swig, but there aren't any options for it on Express generator.

How can I create this common structure using Express and Swig faster?

Comment: [Swig has support for Express built-in](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#express). What have you tried? Are you referring to a Yeoman generator? If so, which one? [This](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-express)? Another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer [Swig with Express.js](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#express)

In that there is option to change the default engine from Jade to HTML

```
var app = require('express')(),
  swig = require('swig'),
  people;

// This is where all the magic happens!
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);

app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Comment: in your answer why you write people; after requiring swig explain me in details why to use people;

Comment: @RiteshDhuri: I have provided the link for reference, I have just copied the snippet and pasted it here.

Answer (score 0):

because of less reputation i unable to comment your answer.
@Sreekesh Okky

in your answer why you write people; after requiring swig explain me in details why to use people;

Comment: It's just a variable name... It doesn't matter for your answer